# Pentaho Transformation "Execute SQL Statements" vs "Table Input" step

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to PDI/Kettle.I need to execute simple SQL select similar to "SELECT EMPID FROM Employee" and need to write the output to "Microsoft Excel Output" as part of reports generation.

1. When I write this query in **"Execute SQL Statement"** step under "SQL Scripts to execute" section in my transformation and execute it , it is returning nothing but transformation got completed without any errors.
   **No result written in my output file**. The same behavior with the step "Execute Row SQL Script" by reading the input from sql file/data grid with query as input.

**Transformation flow:**

> EXECUTE SQL STATEMENTS >> Microsoft Excel Output
>   EXECUTE SQL
>   STATEMENTS >> Textfile Output

2. If I  use "Table Input" step and write the query under "SQL" section , it is getting executed and giving the result.

> Table Input >> Microsoft Excel Output
>   Table Input >> Textfile Output

Can anyone help me in understanding this behavior and context/use cases of these steps.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you techies for your knowledge share on this .
**As per my understanding ,"Execute SQL statement" step is used to execute SQL statements like DDL, DML but it won't give any result to output stream except number of records impacted/affected(statistics) when we execute DML statements.**

To track this statistics, there were optional fields give like **insert stats, update stats, delete stats and read stats** and based on your DML statement we can give the field name and number of records affected will be written as a value to that field. This can be noticed in "Preview data" under Transformation Execution results.

Answer (score 1):

The `Execute SQL Statement` does not provide any result. Its purpose is DDL (Data Definition Language) to drop/create/truncate/alter tables, and DML (Data Manipulation Language) insert/update/delete rows.

Two checks (among other) should become a second nature after the coding of every step:

1. Check the output columns (right click on the step, choose `Output fields`).
2. Make a preview of the results (right click on the step, choose `Preview`).

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain one basic concept of pentaho pdi (kettle): all the actions on kettle happens with a row. If there is no row, there will be no action. So if you add a **generate row** step at the begining of your transformation, with one dummy row with some value you will see how your sql statement will be triggered.

At a glance pentaho works with this 2 premises:

1 Everything is an asyncronous flow

2 Every action happens at row level. (no row, no action)
an input table step generates rows but an execute sql statement is not a input step type, is a transform step and expects rows generated already before this step.
I think this two basics concepts can help to understand how ketle works.